# Play HVDVD_TS EVO with DVD Player?

Tags: macos, dvd-player

How can we play a DVD with an HVDVD_TS folder and EVO files inside using DVD Player?

DVD Player says, "There was a problem opening the media. The media type is not supported."

The DVD plays with DVD Player on a Mac Pro 2008 with Mac OS X Snow Lepoard to OS X ML, but does not play on a Retina MacBook Pro with Lion or Mountain Lion.

The Mac Pro had Final Cut Studio 2, FCS 3, FCPX, iLife '09, iDVD 11. The MacBook did not have FCS 2.

Are we missing a codec? Did Leopard have codecs for HVDVD_TS?

We can play EVO files using VLC, but VLC plays the video with a loud buzz in the left audio channel.

Comment: Are you using an external DVD drive on the devices where it doesn't work?

Comment: We tried it with an external DVD drive and with an ISO of the disk. It's not the drive.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with [VLC player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html). The newest version supports the retina display

Comment: We can play EVO files using VLC, but VLC plays the video with a loud buzz in the left audio channel.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving [Niceplayer](http://code.google.com/p/niceplayer/), it's replaced VLC for me for a lot of applications.

Comment: very nice player. thx for the tip. +1